# Image.enabled в Unity не работает

Tags: c#, 2d

В 2D игре которую я делаю есть код который выбирает случайное число от 1-го до 5-ти, потом из 5 изображений должно будет запуститься одно привязанное к определенной цифре.

```
public class Canvas_1 : MonoBehaviour
{
    public RawImage Q;
    public RawImage W;
    public RawImage E;
    public RawImage F;
    public RawImage B;
    public Image Yes;
    public Image Heck;
   public static System.Random RNG = new System.Random();
   int QTE = RNG.Next(1,6);

    void Start()
    {
        Q.enabled = false;
        W.enabled = false;
        E.enabled = false;
        F.enabled = false;
        B.enabled = false;
        Yes.enabled = false;
        Heck.enabled = false;

        if (QTE == 1)
        {
            Q.enabled = true;
        }
        else if (QTE == 2)
        {
            W.enabled = true;
        }
        else if (QTE == 3)
        {
            E.enabled = true;
        }
        else if (QTE == 4)
        {
            F.enabled = true;
        }
        else if (QTE == 5)
        {
            B.enabled = true;
        }

    }

}
```

Ошибок нету, но ни одно изображение не появлялось. Я что-то делаю не так?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: Вот изображение иерархии и инспектора Image которые попросили. Надеюсь это поможет]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ваш Canvas, и его `Render Mode` скорее всего не настроен, исправьте на `Screen Space - Camera`. И вложите в `Render Camera` свою `Camera`. И отрегулируйте при необходимости `Plane Distance`.

Проверьте `Order in Layer`. Возможно что закрывает элементы.

[image: Canvas]

Возможно, Вы отключаете при старте сам компонент `Image`, а вместе с этим скорее всего у Вас отключен объект, вы пытаетесь включить компонент `Image` а `GameObject` отключен, поэтому ничего и не получается. Вам нужно либо включать/отключать именно компонент `Image` и не отключать `GameObject` или отключать `GameObject` затем его включать, но не трогать компонент `Image`.

Если Вам нужен объект попробуйте

```
Q.gameObject.SetActive(true);
```

Вот как это реализовать для вашего варианта.

```
public Image Q;

public static System.Random RNG = new System.Random();
int QTE = RNG.Next(1, 6);

void Start()
{
    if (QTE == 1)
    {
        Q.gameObject.SetActive(true);
    }
}
```

В таком варианте у меня получилось показать объект, у которого был включён компонент `Image`. Не работайте с отключением компонента отдельно от `GameObject` если это не цель вашей задачи

Comment: Здравствуйте, я попытался сперва заменить enabled на SetActive, и потом использовать их вместе. В обоих случаях не выходило.

Comment: @WAYRT Подправил свой ответ, ознакомьтесь пожалуйста, скорее всего он решает вашу проблему

Comment: Я переписал код в предоставленной вами манере и ничего не изменилось.

Comment: @WAYRT на сцене ваши объекты отключены? Можете дополнить ваш вопрос **скриншотом** вашего окна `Hierachy` где показаны ваши `Image` и `Inspector` где показаны компонент `Image`

Comment: Готово, надеюсь это поможет.

Comment: @WAYRT я смогу посмотреть на Ваш проект? Возможно дело в чём то ещё. Свяжитесь со мной в [VK](https://vk.com/almn98)